# Remove Shipping Method for Virtual Product Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, virtual-products

We are having strange problem,
On checkout for Magento 2.3.2, 
For Virtual products or gift card
(we checked if its gift card extension issue, but it is also happening for virtual product whose weight is set as this item have not weight)
 it is asking shipping address and shows shipping block
which is resulting in "No Quotes available"
Further resulting in unable to place order as there is no shipping method available

Because of which we are loosing sales

(This is also happening on Magento's Luma and Blank theme)

Comment: Have you checked the same on default Magento without any extension?

Comment: Are you using any third party checkout module?

Comment: We are using Codazon's fastest Magento2 theme

Answer (score 0):

You should disable codazon one step checkout module.
It breaks checkout for virtual products.

php bin/magento module:disable Codazon_OneStepCheckout

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

And then deploy your static files.

It will work now.